# Why does saved graphic not look the same as graphic in notebook?

Tags: plotting

```
g1 = Plot[(x^2 - 4 x + 3)/(x + 1), {x, -5, 5}];

Rotate[g1, -90 Degree]
```

After saving the output of the rotated graph, I still get the graph of `g1`.

[image]

I get

[image]

Comment: What happens if you write `g2 = Rotate[g1, -90 °]` and save `g2`?

Comment: @m_goldberg still not good,,, save cell as picture could get the right result

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. When I save g2 with `Export`, I get the rotated image.

Comment: @m_goldberg oh,the problem is not by `Export`, is by mouse right-click the output image to save the image.

Comment: Still can not reproduce. When I right-click and do Save Selection As..., I still get rotated image.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem on V9.0.1 on OS X. What version of _Mathematica_ on what OS are you using?

Comment: @m_goldberg 9.0.1 on Windows 8 x64

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9419/discussion-between-m-goldberg-and-hypergroups)

Comment: For me, Save Selection As... (on cell bracket) saves a rotated image, as does Export. Only Save Graphic As... saves the image without the rotation.

Comment: @cormullion yours are same to mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the underlying Cell expression, you'll find the Cell is structured as

```
Cell[BoxData[
    RotationBox[
        GraphicsBox[ (* ... *) ],
        BoxRotation -> -1.5707963267948966`]
    ], "Output"]
```

So when you select **the orange framed object**, you're actually selecting only the `GraphicsBox[]`, without the effect of the `RotationBox`.

If you select the whole cell content (*e.g.* by dragging the mouse), and then **Save Selection As...**, you should get the expected result.

[image: demonstration]

Comment: Hi, why @m_goldberg 's environment does not produce such results? `CellExpression`s are different in different machines?

Comment: +1 I always feel the whole `Rotate` things is quite opaque and not always as useful as it should be.

Comment: @hypergroups Save Selection and Save Graphics are different, apparently - m_goldberg and I have the same environment....

Comment: @cormullion ok, maybe m_goldberg haven't save graphics...

Comment: @HyperGroups My guess is the same as cormullion.

Comment: My failure to reproduce the problem on OS X was because of inattention on my part. My tests were conducted with `Export` and Save Selection As..... They were made before HyperGroups edited his post and added the screen captures. I didn't notice after the captures appeared that he was clicking on ShowGraphicsAs..., which is also available on OS X and produces the results he reported in that environment as well.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks. I usually use it as a primitive, so there is less chance to see issues like this.

Comment: @m_goldberg Good to know! :)

Comment: @Silvia but even for graphics primitives, I find it odd that the transformation is only carried out during rendering and as such for serious calculations not always accessible.

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes I find it inconvenient sometimes, too. But unfortunately, at present we don't have a good enough alternative..